# Create X_test, X_train, Y_test, Y_train in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following scheme:

```
training_filenames = filenames[split:]
validation_filenames = filenames[:split]
```

see: https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/fast-and-lean-data-science/04_Keras_Flowers_transfer_learning_solution.ipynb#scrollTo=M3G-2aUBQJ-H

Now I want to create `x_train`, `y_train` and `x_test` and `y_test` (for `Hyperparameter Tuning`). How is it done properly?

There are different classes available (`CLASSES = ['daisy', 'dandelion', 'roses', 'sunflowers', 'tulips']`)

Comment: if you split `training_filenames` then you will have `y_train` and `y_test`. And when you load images then they will be `x_train`, `x_test`

Comment: what do you have in `filenames` ? Do you have names of images `jpg`, `png` ? Can you use `names` as labels`?

Comment: I checked you link and you should first load all files using `load_dataset()` which gives dataset with `image, label` - and then you can try to split it into `train`, `test`, and later split `train`  into `x_train = train.image, y_train = train.label`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the classes aren't that important. I assume each file contains an image and a label (it seems like it from the example you refer to). As I understand, you want not only train and validation data but train, validation and test data.

You should be able to do so like this:

```py
# splits of your choice; this split leaves 10% of testing data
TRAINING_SPLIT = .7
VALIDATION_SPLIT = .2

training_filenames = filenames[:int(len(filenames) * TRAINING_SPLIT)]
validation_filenames = filenames[int(len(filenames) * TRAINING_SPLIT):int(len(filenames) * (TRAINING_SPLIT + VALIDATION_SPLIT))]
testing_filenames = filenames[int(len(filenames) * (TRAINING_SPLIT + VALIDATION_SPLIT)):]
```

Then you can proceed reading in the data as is done in the example. Once that is done, you should be able to extract the X (image) and y (label) data if needed.

Comment: Okay sorry maybe my post was a litte bit confusing. I understand you code and it is clear for me. But I want to have the following structure:

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

So I want x_train and x_test (and also y_train and y_test) out of your posted code (I just need training and testing, validation is not necessary)

Comment: I indeed misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data as NumPy arrays, you should first load the data using the `load_dataset()` function from the example. This returns a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset)). Looking at the `display utilities` code in your example, there is a function that does exactly what you want to do, except it only extracts the first `N` input-output pairs:

```py
def dataset_to_numpy_util(dataset, N):
  dataset = dataset.batch(N)
  
  for images, labels in dataset:
    numpy_images = images.numpy()
    numpy_labels = labels.numpy()
    break;

  return numpy_images, numpy_labels
```

You should be able to do the following:

```py
X_train, y_train = dataset_to_numpy_util(load_dataset(training_filenames), len(training_filenames))
X_test, y_test = dataset_to_numpy_util(load_dataset(testing_filenames), len(testing_filenames))
```